# How to get data (of my api json) in my object ( Redux, React )?

Tags: json, reactjs, redux

I not undestand everything with javascript etc, I want to get my data returned by ma action redux but i'have a problem with my code.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    const group = state.groupReducer.group ? state.groupReducer.group  : [ ]
    return {
        group
    }
```

how i can get my data ?

[image: x]

When I try with that:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    const group = state.groupReducer.group.data.data[0] ? state.groupReducer.group.data.data[0]  : [ ]
    return {
        group
    }
```

[image: x]

And my goal is map around `group`

```
    renderGroup = group => {
    return group.map((groups => {
        <div key={groups.data.data.id}>
        //
        </div>
    }))
}
```

Sagas.js

```
 export function* loadApiDataGroup() {
  try {
  // API 
    const response = yield 
    call(axios.get,'http://localhost:8000/api/group');
    yield put(loadGroup(response))
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('REQUEST FAILED! Could not get group.')
     console.log(e)
     }
      }
```

Action.js

```
 export function loadGroup(data){ return { type: LOAD_GROUP, data }};
 export function creatGroup(data){ return { type: CREATE_GROUP, data}};
```

// reducer

```
     export default function groupReducer( state= {}, action = {}){
     switch (action.type){
      case LOAD_GROUP:
        return {
            ...state,
            group: action.data
        }
     case CREATE_GROUP:
        return {
            ...state
        }
    default:
        return state
}
```

thank you to help me

Comment: Show the code where you do that Ajax request that you are printing.

Comment: Add your action creator and reducer related to your groups, so we can understand what's going on.

Comment: yes i've add my request ajax and actions with reducer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    group: state.groupReducer.group || []
});
```

Then you can use `this.props.group` in the component. Even though you might only want one thing in `mapStateToProps`, it's usually not directly returned like that.

If `group` is the response of an API request, you need to unpack `data` first, this is done in your async action creator (you will want to use redux-thunk or something similar):

```
const getGroup = () => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'GET_GROUP_REQUEST' });
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.get('/some/url');
        dispatch({ type: 'GET_GROUP_SUCCESS', payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({ type: 'GET_GROUP_FAILURE', payload: error });
    }
};
```

Comment: ok thank you :) i'm trying now. and i'have add my request ajax in my post

Comment: problem is résolut, i have do like that export function*  
       `loadApiDataGroup() {
         try {
     // API 
            const response = yield call(axios.get, 
            'http://localhost:8000/api/group');
             yield put(loadGroup(response.data.data))
          } catch (e) {
            console.log('REQUEST FAILED! Could not get group.')
                console.log(e)
              }
           }`